# Mobile browser (iPhone) unable to display very big image (e.g. 4096 x 4096)

Tags: image

How do you display a very big image on mobile?

For example, the following will appear on desktop but will not appear on my iPhone:

```
<img src="someReallyBigImage.png" width="4096" height="4096" />
```

Anybody able to display such a big image on their mobile browser?

Thanks!

Comment: are you sure it's not the mobile browser that's preventing you from displaying the image?

Comment: I think it's the mobile browser running out of memory while trying to display big images. But I'm not sure.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this is not the solution to your problem but adding the responsive class to your image might solve the problem:

> Images in Bootstrap 3 can be made responsive-friendly via the addition
>   of the .img-responsive class. This applies max-width: 100%; and
>   height: auto; to the image so that it scales nicely to the parent
>   element.

```
<img src="..." class="img-responsive" alt="Responsive image">
```

Comment: Thanks Amin, I'm aware of the responsive class. However, the image (4096 x 4096) does not even appear, whether responsive or not. I think its the iPhone memory limit hit? Not sure though.